# how to add emoji country flag unicode in android studio xml file

Tags: java, android, unicode, android-softkeyboard, emoji

I am developing a custom keyboard.For adding emoji,i have use a xml file in  android studio and 
for each emoji write following code in each row

```
<Key android:codes="0x1F603" android:keyIcon="@drawable/emoji_icon" android:keyWidth="12.5%p"/>
```

0x1f603 is the unicode of the emoji_icon.emoji_icon is the particular image of the emoji that store in drawable folder that works fine.
Now when i try add country flag emoji,there are two unicode such as 
for Australia U+1F1E6 U+1F1FA .I am try by the following code

```
    <Key android:codes="0x1F1E6 0x1F1FA" android:keyIcon="@drawable/flag" android:keyWidth="12.5%p"/>
```

But it is not work .Can any body tell me how can i do this by programmatically?